# SSRS Dynamic Subscription - how to use parameter in file name

Tags: reporting-services, data-driven

How do I write the FileName to show 'Name ' + `DespatchFrom` + '-' + `DespatchTo` as FileName

Those values are parameters but I keep getting validation errors.

I have also tried 'Name ' + `DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1-WeekDay(Today), Today())` as FileName
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unless your date fields are in already a text field, you'll need to convert them otherwise you'll get a conversion error.

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

The Data Driven query needs SQL syntax which is why your second attempt with TODAY failed.

I think you want something like

```
SELECT 'Name ' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), DespatchFrom, 110) + ' - ' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), DespatchTo, 110)  as FileName
```

Comment: Thank you, pure SQL was the key takeaway here :)

Answer (score 1):

you don't need data driven .. you only want to add the date end of file name. you can use parameter `@timestamp`

[image]